# Xamarin Android: Detect if audio is currently playing on device

Tags: android, audio, xamarin

At app launch, is it possible to detect if the device's audio player or another app is currently playing music?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`AudioManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) to achieve this with it's [`IsMusicActive`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#isMusicActive()) property:

```
AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService (Android.Content.Context.AudioService);
var audioDetails = "Audio is " + (manager.IsMusicActive ? "on" : "off");
```

Comment: From my testing, this will return true also if a music app is opened but not actually playing. Some other comments on SO mention that IsMusicActive is set to true always on some devices. So it does not quite do what you want, but there does not seem to be any other way.