# Getting data from any sound currently playing on an android device?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am interested to get any sound currently playing on a mobile device, even if it is not playing using the app. Is it possible to monitor the speakers, and get data directly before they play that sound? Like when you plug in the headphones and the speaker stops, but android sends the data to the headset, no matter, where it is playing. If it is, what would be the code?

I did look at this, but this should get only if it is playing or not, and not actuall song data.

[Xamarin Android: Detect if audio is currently playing on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32833722/xamarin-android-detect-if-audio-is-currently-playing-on-device)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the microphone, except when earphones are connected, like Shazam does or the ROG phone to sync the rgb with the audio.

Comment: Wouldn't that also record any additional sound the mic picks up?

Comment: Oh yes, did not think about that, maybe try using the playback capture API, as long as I know is still active.